# How to remove unmarked icons from app drawer?

Tags: lineageos, app-drawer

I have few icons at the bottom of my app drawer, that are unmarked. I don't know what apps they represent and look like an unfinished installation. They look like this:

[image: screenshot]

How can I get rid of them?

I already tried cleaning cache of Trebuchet and Play Store. 
This may be a bug in OS, because I am running unofficial build of LineageOS 17 (Android 10 based) on my device. Nevertheless, is there a way to remove those icons?

Comment: Did you reboot after clearing cache of launcher? That helps at times. If not use free version of this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm) to clean system, and also corpse finder (since you indicated aborted installs)